# how to iterate through a nested list element by element to create a different string each time

Tags: python

I'm doing some practice problems and I'm trying to figure out how to go through nested lists so that it does this:

```
example list: [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','j']]
expected: ['a','ab','abc','b','bc','c']
```

and it does this for each list
what I've tried doing so far:

```
    idk = ""
    for i in range(len(example_list)):
        idk.join(example_list[i][i:i+1])
```

im confused on to go one by one when ive tried other ways i just get a huge string

Comment: can you put the full expected list for a shorter example? because I don't see a `'ac'` in you expected list and I'm not sure if it's a coincidence or just not part of the pattern.

Comment: I can't understand the expected output. Why doesn't it have `'ac'`? Why doesn't it have `''`? Why doesn't it have anything that includes any of the content from lists besides the first `['a','b','c']` list? Why are those other lists there at all?

Comment: it only supposed to occur if those indexes are next to each other and goes till it reaches the end of list and when that happens it goes on to start at the next index if that makes sense

Comment: i didnt know if i needed to do the other lists since it would be the same out come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words=[]    
for i in list:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        k=j;
        temp=""
        while k<len(i):
            temp+=i[k]
            words.append(temp)
```

I think this is what you are looking for